Book about a woman in a wheelchair who ends up getting pulled into a game she was playing; in the game world, her chair has mechanical spider legs
I can't remember the name of a book I would like to reread. It's about a woman in a wheelchair that plays a game that she ends up getting pulled into. She is in the game world in a chair that has mechanical spider legs so that she can get through the world.

Welcome Elliana. What else do you remember; the language of the book, when you read it (and was it old then or newish), was there cover art that struck you?

Unfortunately it's been a couple years and it was on Kindle. The book was in English.

How many is "a couple"? Technically it's 2 years, but some people use it pretty loosely and it could be 10 or more... Was it a new release then or an older book that was new to you?
